# How can I resolve the error: "The command [...] exited with code 1"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I've read around many questions but I've not been able to find the right answer for me.

As I try to compile a project in VS2012 I have this result:

The command "....\tools\bin\nuget pack Packages\Lib.Html.nuspec -    OutputDirectory ....\bin\Zip\Packages -NoPackageAnalysis" exited with code 1.

I looked for the line of code in my .csproj file, where the error should be, and there is:

```
<Exec Command="$(ProjectDir)..\..\tools\bin\nuget pack $(ProjectDir)Packages\Lib.Html.nuspec -OutputDirectory $(OutputPath)Packages -NoPackageAnalysis" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT] 
Launching the Debug of that project and ignoring "building errors", I have a new alert:

"Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target '[project.exe path]' is missing.
Please build the project and retry, or set OutputPath and AssemblyName properties appropriately to point at the correct location for the target assembly."

Comment: When you say "result" do you mean the "Error list" view? Try to have a look at the "Output" view. There may be additional information.

Comment: Yes, by result I meant Error List. Unfortunately that project is just a class library, but if I start to Debug and I ignore "building errors" a VS alert appears, I edit my question. Hoping it can help :)

Comment: Again, try to have a look at the "Output" view. iIs there additional information in this window? The output view can be found in menu VIEW -> Output

Comment: Check if the file "$(ProjectDir)..\..\tools\bin\nuget pack $(ProjectDir)Packages\Lib.Html.nuspec" exists

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The first step is figuring out what the error actually is.  In order to do this expand your MsBuild output to be diagnostic.  This will reveal the actual command executed and hopefully the full error message as well

- Tools -> Options
- Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run
- Change "MsBuild project build output verbosity" to "Diagnostic".

Comment: Turns out I didn't have quotes around the paths so when I introduced a space in that path it exited with code 1. This method helped me find that out.

Comment: Great advice! You, sir, have my upvote :D
However, the "Diagnostic" option gave me WAY too much data. Setting it to "Normal" got me the info I needed while still being manageable :)
Turns out I had the wrong powershell "execute policy". Fixed by running "Set-ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -Scope CurrentUser" in powershell.

Comment: Thanks!. Your comment helped. One of the projects referenced in the build events was in locked state. Doing svncleanup on the project folder fixed my issue

Comment: Thanks!  Was a simple syntax error (missing space) for my case. Very useful to know this trick. Verbose was a bit of a fire hose of info so I set mine on Detailed and that was enough to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: I git cloned right into my F:/ drive and there was no more problems.  Perhaps the problem was because I git cloned into a project folder whose name has spaces in it.  Lesson:  Do not have spaces in folder/file names.

Comment: Thank you Jared. I just wanted to let you know, you saved my day :-) I got a project from a partner company and I could not figure out why I wasn't able to build the project. As it turned out, I wasn't allowed to use spaces in my project folder's name.

Answer (score 36):

Right click project -> Properties -> Build Events

Remove the text in Post-build event command line text block

Comment: Thanks! Project had some commands in Pre build events which were failing, removing which solved issue for me.

Comment: I would advise against removing Pre/Post build commands without understanding what they are supposed to do and why they are failing. Sometimes you may be missing important setups that are done on the projects which are running them.

Answer (score 7):

Try to open Visual Studio as admin.

Comment: This was the answer for me when trying to run a PowerShell script as a post-build event

Comment: this worked for me too. Didn't have to change any VS Setting.

Answer (score 7):

For me : I have a white space in my path's folder name `G:\Other Imp Projects\Mi.....`

### **Solution 1 :**

Remove white space from folder

Example: `Other Imp Projects` ->> `Other_Imp_Projects`

### **Solution 2:**

add Quote (`""`) for your path.

Example: `mkdir "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Configurations"`  //see double quotes

Answer (score 2):

For me, in VS 2013, I had to get rid of missing references under References in the UI project (MVC). Turns out, the ones missing were not referenced.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too late for sure, but, this could help someone as well.

In my case, i found that the source file is being used by another process which was restricting from copying to the destination. I found that by using command prompt ( just copy paste the post build command to the command prompt and executed gave me the error info).

Make sure that you can copy from the command prompt,

Answer (score 1):

This builds on the answer from JaredPar... and is for VS2017.  The same "Build and Run" options are present in Visual Studio 2017.

I was getting, The command "chmod +x """ exited with code 1

In the build output window, I searched for "Error" and found a few errors in the same general area.  I was able to click on a link in the build output, and found that the error involved this entry in the .targets file:

```
  <Target Name="ChmodChromeDriver" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(WebDriverPlatform)' != 'win32'">
    <Exec Command="chmod +x &quot;$(ChromeDriverSrcPath)&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

In the build output, I also found a more detailed error message that essentially stated that it couldn't find Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver v2.36 in the packages folder it was looking in.  I checked the project's NuGet packages, and version 2.36 was indeed in the list of installed packages.  I did find the package files for 2.36, and changed the attributes on the folder, subfolders and files from "Read Only" to "Read/Write".  Built, but same failure.  Sometimes "updating" to a different version of the package and then updating back to the original can fix this type of error.  So I "updated" the reference in Manage NuGet packages to 2.37, built, failed, then "updated" back to 2.36, built, and the build succeeded without the "chmod +x" error message.

The project I was building was based on a Visual Studio Project template for Appium test tooling, template name "Develop_Automated_Test".

Answer (score 1):

**Check your paths**:
If you are using a separate build server for TFS (most likely), make sure that all your paths in the .csproj file *match the **TFS server** paths*.  I got the above error when checking in the *.csproj file when it had references to my development machine paths and not the TFS server paths.

**Remove multi-line commands**: Also, try and remove multi-line commands into single-line commands in xml as a precaution.  I had the following xml in the *.proj that caused issues in TFS:

```
<Exec Condition="bl.." 
Command=" Blah...
..." </Exec>
```

Changing the above xml to this worked:

```
  <Exec Condition="bl.." Command=" Blah..." </Exec>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hint: Search for "Exec Command=" in your project**

In my case I found following tag in "Microsoft.Extensions.ApiDescription.Server.targets" file, I remarked the line and it worked for me:

```
<Exec Command="$(_Command)" LogStandardErrorAsError="true" />
```

Comment: This helped me diagnose the issue. Changing `<Exec Command="powershell Script.ps1" />` to `<Exec Command="powershell ./Script.ps1" />` solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Tried all the above answers. It was actually complained about a .dll file. I clean the project in Visual Studio but the .dll file still remains, so I deleted in manually from the bin folder and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone, but I had prebuild events and post build events and it kept complaining about a file called "Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" "The target "CoreBuild" does not exist in the project".

Here's what I did to resolve it:

1. close the project
2. delete the .suo file (it regenerates)
3. Asked a team member to provide a copy of that file (Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets) - mine was different - I took his.
4. It compiled - good to go.

I must have wrecked that file somehow.

Answer (score 0):

There was no syntax error in my batch file and it ran fine on a cmd prompt outside VS.
So finally, I added

```
exit 0
```

to return a success code explicitly at the end of my batch file and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

For me the output file (.dll) of the same version already existed so I guess it was having trouble overwriting. Even though it has never done it before. Anyways, deleting the existing file and running Rebuild fixed it for me.

If the previous method wouldn't have fixed it, my next check would have been to check if the path length was causing it. So would have change the target folder to somewhere close like the Desktop so that the path isnt too long.

Answer (score 0):

Running `dotnet swagger` from the command line in the solution root returned this error:

`Run "dotnet tool restore" to make the "swagger" command available.`

Following the recommendation solved the problem.