# I get error while I build my solution

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have an architecture with so many layers and projects. Generally I get a common error while I build my solution and I really don't get why am I getting this error. I have attached my architecture and error images. Please help me if you know about this error and how to get rid of it[image]

[image]

Comment: when i close visual studio and again open it then it work fine.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it happens, most probably because the dll is already in use by other application or the app is running probably. Close and re-open VS.

Comment: is there any other solution?

Comment: Well, what I commented is the solution I know of.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a fxcop report xml, trying checking it... you should find an exception message that will tell you more about the error.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this stupid errors too long time ago when I was a student :)
<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Esc</kbd> (Task Manager). Check if there is nothing running in background that's related to your application.

Comment: Sir actually i saw task manager.there is nothing running related to my project.but i noticed one thing there is a file named Company.Project.sln.FxCop is in the folder where i have Company.Project.sln.
can you please tell me there is any relation of this file to my error

Comment: You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151402/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-the-command-exited-with-code-1) SO post or [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/589ffae3-59ca-4d0a-a7b1-9f1120db3792/msb3073-the-command-exited-with-code-3?forum=msbuild). If they didn't help, tell google to search for you "VS The command exited with code 3".