# Command exited with code 1 in Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.Targets file , after upgrading visual studio from 2012 to 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, upgrade

After upgrading Visual Studio from 2012 to 2015, got a build error, as follows,

> Command "" exited with code 1 in
>   Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.Targets file

when I clicked on the error, file got opened as shown below, with the line,
[image]

all the path variables in macors in pre and post build events are pointed to 14.0 version of VS.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151402/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-the-command-exited-with-code-1)?

Comment: yes, but still getting the error

Comment: I find strange that the Command is calling itself... PreBuildEvent is both the value of Command and the name of Target?

Comment: @Prasu, do you have custom pre and post build in your solution? If so, please share it  or go to Tools-Options-Projects and Solutions-Build and Run, set MSBuild project build output verbosity as "Detailed", then build it again and share the detail error message.