# getting error: The command "copy /Y "C:\Users\.....exe" "..\..\..\..\publish\FrameExtract-AnyCPU.exe"" exited with code 1 how to fix it?

Tags: c#, winforms

the error happens when i tried to build it in visual studio.  Build > Rebuild Solution

when I make right click on the project file on the hard disk I don't have any option to run it as admin.

> `The command "copy /Y "C:\Users\user\Downloads\FrameExtract-master\FrameExtract-master\FrameExtract\bin\Debug\FrameExtract.exe" "..\..\..\..\publish\FrameExtract-AnyCPU.exe"" exited with code 1.    FrameExtract`

Comment: Have you tried rebooting Visual Studio and your machine?

Comment: This post may be useful: [How can I resolve the error: The command exited with code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151402/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-the-command-exited-with-code-1?rq=2)

Comment: Why is your solution building stuff in the downloads folder. That is weird to start with.

Comment: copy /Y "C:\Users\Chocolade 1972\Downloads\FrameExtract-master\FrameExtract-master\FrameExtract\bin\Debug\FrameExtract.exe" "..\..\..\..\publish\FrameExtract-AnyCPU.exe"
  The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: @rene I downloaded the project as zip from github and then extracted the zip file and then tried to build it from the folder.   downloaded from here: https://github.com/SeinopSys/FrameExtract

Comment: @rene I will copy it to d: some folder and will try to build it there but I havn't got this error before when tried to build/run from the downloads folder.

Comment: Did you extract and/or create the publish folder? Needs to be created where the solution file is.

Comment: @rene i see the folder in the publish publishing folder location: publish\

Comment: is there a way to build it without publishing ?

Comment: @rene and i checked now the publish folder is already exist after extracting the zip file.  and in the publish folder there are two exe files of the application 64 and 32 bit and I can run the 64 bit.

Comment: Anyway: your problem is here: https://github.com/SeinopSys/FrameExtract/blob/master/FrameExtract/FrameExtract.csproj#L161 that needs to be two valid paths. I'm not a big fan of relative paths when it is to be left to the calling process to be in the right working directory. Just drop that line.